# Rounding a percentage to the nearest whole number

Tags: javascript

I have a own made grid system, and i have to calculate every size for a column.

In each `row` fits `12` columns. Wich is the case in every example code i'm going to give below.

When calculating the percentages for the grid sizes, these numbers are not always whole numbers, mostly like:

```
99.98029427220177
100.01970572779821
100.0146484375
100.009765625
100.01464843750001
100.00976562499999
```

When i use `Math.floor` in javascript i get this:

```
94
96
98
99
98
99
```

And this is want i want:

```
100
100
100
100
100
100
```

So all rounded up to a whole percentage.

Comment: `Math.floor(99.98029427220177) == 99` ... how are you getting those results?

Comment: the results you posted are wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/439yr/ The first value is 99 and the other values will be floored to 100.

Comment: And why do you use Javascript to calculate the widths of grid columns? You can do all this with css only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this.

1. If you are just presenting the value to the DOM then the built in JavaScript toFixed() method is what you are looking for:

Here I'll give a quick rundown:

```
(99.790980).toFixed() # => "100"
(99.790980).toFixed(1) # => "99.8"
(100.23232).toFixed() # => "100"
(100.23232).toFixed(1) # => "100.2"
```

Most of the time, these values are being shoved into the `DOM`. Under the scenes, Number gets converted with `toString()` for the browser to draw it to the screen. This is a really simple, built-in API for `Number`. Keep in mind that you get a `String` as a return value. If you want to convert it back to a `Number` type to continue math then you can use the following pattern:

```
function preciseMathDotRound(value, precision = 0) {
  return parseFloat(value.toFixed(precision));
}

// preciseMathDotRound(99.919191) == 100
// preciseMathDotRound(99.919191, 1) == 99.9
```

2. Math.round is a Math API for rounding numbers. The API does not include precision so it only rounds to the nearest integer. The return value is a number.

   Math.round(99.790980) # => 100
   Math.round(100.23232) # => 100

Comment: Thank you, didnt know. Is it like `Math.round`?

Answer (score 11):

Math.round(x)

--

Example:

Math.round(99.5) == 100

Math.round(99.49) == 99